# Help Choose the Speakers and Talks for Dev Days 2011 [San Francisco]

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2011

We need your help to pick what speakers and talks you want to hear at [Dev Days 2011](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com)!  We're looking for 3-4 people (for each city) to join our Curriculum Committees - this group will be responsible for selecting the topics being covered and the speakers giving those talks.

This role has a lot of responsibility (since you'll be picking all the content for Dev Days).  Ideal members should be heavily involved in the SO community, know the topics that people will find interesting, and have the time over the next month to put in at least 5 hours a week discussing options with your fellow committee members.  Also, please only nominate yourself for the committee in the city that you are planning on attending Dev Days.

So, if you're interested in joining the curriculum committee, please submit your name as an answer below, along with a couple of sentences about why you'll be a strong addition to the team.  You can also vote up people who you think would be good (the top 4 vote-getters aren't guaranteed to be the ones we select, but it will certainly weigh heavily in our decision).

Look forward to seeing you all at Dev Days 2011!

Comment: It would probably help if we had an exact location for the event.

Comment: I'm thinking 99% chance this will be in the Bay Area...

Comment: Yes. I was leaving open the possibility that it might be Seattle, but apparently there are far more venues in the Bay Area that can accomodate us, somewhere between San Francisco and San Jose.

Comment: @Joel @Jeff I guess more nominees are going to sign up if you alter US West Coast in the title to Bay Area.

Comment: @NickLarsen: I have VERY high standards ;-)

Comment: If anyone else is interested in being on the curriculum committee for Dev Days (San Francisco, October 12-13), please send me an email by 6/7: alison@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 15):

I can help. I'm good at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to nominate myself. As a Developer Evangelist, I spend my days at conferences listening to speaker after speaker so I know what makes a good one. I'll be based in San Francisco starting next month as well so I'll be close to the community there. Lastly I work for [a company](http://www.twilio.com) that is focused entirely on software developers, so we have a good sense of what the current trends and topics developers are interested in. As a company we are also well-connected to the community in the Bay Area with relationships and access to a ton of interesting people.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to nominate myself if the conference is going to be in the Bay Area (as I'm not sure if I'll be able attend one in Seattle.) I've been an active (read: addicted) member of the Stack Overflow community since a couple years ago, holding a Legendary badge since the day it was introduced.  I posted the first known online photo of [Stack Overflow plaque at Computer History Museum](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-and-the-computer-history-museum/) on meta and I've been seen wearing Stack Overflow t-shirts on many occasions. Need to say more about my Stack Overflow passion?  :)

That said, I've been less active in the past few months and have absolutely zero experience organizing tech conferences, but you should just dive in and do things at times, right?!